# Microsoft SQL Server Managment Studio (SSMS) - Could not launch

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am running Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 17 on a VMWARE 8 virtual machine on MacBook Pro. It was working fine until yesterday.

However, today when I logged in and run SSMS I got following error. I did uninstall Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and re-installed it, but without any success. I look up on Google there all sort of suggestion but nothing worked out for me. Any help would be much appreciated

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: just checking some of those things that didnt work out: downloading sp1 and updating .net framework?.. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/sql-server-management-studio-2014-crashing/52591783-7423-4b1e-96e1-aae39a3fc148

Comment: no it did not help either.